# Dimension of span of powers of a given matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be a matrix $n\times n$ of rank n, then Cayley–Hamilton theorem states that powers of A up to $n-1$ are linearly depend, more preciously $\rho_A(A)=0$ for characteristic polynomial of $A$.

I've stuck with an elementary question, what is the dimension of linear span of powers of A up to k-th power? It seems to be related to the theorem above, but it's not clear for me how understand it and the dimension of the span.

Answer (score 2):

The space of $n \times n$ matrices is a vector space (e.g., just view each matrix as a vector with $n^2$ components).

$\{A^{n-1}, A^{n-2}, \ldots, A, I\}$ is a set of elements of this vector space, so you can consider its span (i.e. all matrices of the form $c_{n-1} A^{n-1} + \cdots + c_1 A + c_0 I$) or ask about whether the set is linearly independent or not, etc. This is not anything different than what you know about working with vector spaces of the form $\mathbb{R}^n$.

If you know that, say, $A^3 + 2 A^2 + 5 A - 2I = 0$ (this is an arbitrary example), then you know $\{A^3, A^2, A, I\}$ is a linearly dependent set. (Why?) Can you now figure out what the Cayley-Hamilton theorem implies about linear dependence of powers of $A$?